# Can't get DTMF tones from sim800L gsm module

Tags: arduino, esp8266, gsm, sim800

I am using esp8266 and sim800L gsm module to recieve incoming call and get the DTMF tones from the caller and take an action according to the received number, i am searching for about 3 days and found nothing.

i use the AT+command "AT+DDET=1" to enable the DTMF tones capturer in the module but nothing happend i also tryied to change the modes and the delay times with this command "AT+DDET=1,1000,1,1" and found nothing

i communicate with the sim800 through Serial communication and send and receive commands through Serial monitor, and that is the code i am using:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <cstring>

#include <Arduino.h>

#define simTX D3
#define simRX D4


SoftwareSerial sim800l(simRX, simTX);  //RX, TX


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200); //Begin serial communication with Arduino and Arduino IDE (Serial Monitor)

  sim800l.begin(115200); //Begin serial communication with Arduino and SIM800L

  Serial.println("Initializing...");
   delay(1000);

}

void loop() {

  updateSerial();

 }

//Start
void updateSerial() {
  delay(500);
  while (Serial.available()) 
  {
    sim800l.write(Serial.read());//Forward what Serial received to Software Serial Port
  }
  while(sim800l.available()) 
  {
    Serial.write(sim800l.read());//Forward what Software Serial received to Serial Port
  }

}
//End
```

and i am using this connecting diagram [image: Sim800L and esp8266 connecting diagram]

the module is responding to all my commands and i can make calls when i connect a microphone with a clear voice but i don't recieve any tones, (I RECIEVED ONLY ONE TONE BUT IT WAS WRONGE) and i couldn't do it again

i tested two sim cards from two different companys and tried to call from multiple phones and found nothing

i don't know if it is a problem from the service provider or a phone problem or module problem

i hope any one can help,
Best regards.

Comment: are you saying that you can hear the caller's voice, but you cannot hear a tone when the caller presses a button on their phone?

Comment: @jsotola Yes exactly

Comment: that makes your whole question irrelevant ... the problem is with the phone ... you cannot receive something that is not sent

Comment: @jsotola but i am pretty sure it is not with the phone because 
1- i tried multiple different phones old and new
2- the same phone work with the IVR systems of all the companys, i tried for example vodafone IVR system

Comment: the tone is audio, same as voice ... call another phone and determine if the tones are heard on the second phone

Comment: @jsotola thank you so much i thought we don't hear the DTMF tones, when i tried to call from my phone to phone2 i heared it in my phone but i didn't hear it in the phone2 so i thought that as you mentioned it is my phone's issue, but i tried from phone3 to phone2 and i didn't hear it also, while knowing that all that phones work with the DTMF tones in the IVR systems in all the companies, so how do you think they get it, can it be different method?